# why do virtual machines run slow on jump drive and how to speed them up?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have been using Parallels Desktop on my MacBook Pro for some time now and everything has been working fine.  To save some disk space, I have moved the Virtual Machine images to a 128GB USB 3.0 jump drive.  Although everything still works fine in the virtual machine, it runs slow when there are I/O operations.  I am able to download large files inside the virtual machine without issues.

The slow down is most noticeable when I am using [docker](https://www.docker.com/) inside my virtual machine.  When i use

```
docker pull 'imagename'
```

it downloads very quickly but extracting take a long time.

How can I speed up my Virtual Machine when I run it from a 3.0 jump drive?

Comment: What file system is the jump drive using?  but from most of my experience IO on them is generally pretty crappy,  especially once you get into random reads/writes.  And the marketing numbers that you see on them are BS (ie peak not sustained).. I've moved to using SSDs (recovered from dead laptops) for this, and they performance is way better than even higher end jump/flash drives

Comment: Thanks for your response @Doon.  The file system is exFAT.  Is there any particular file system that performs better than others?  Although I could use an external 3.0 hard drive to speed things up but my intension was to use a jump drive due to its smaller size.

Comment: I don't have any data on speed differences. Was mostly just curious.  Unless you need to share the Jump Drive with Windows, I would use HFS+ as it is native to osx.  You could always try both and see if difference.